# Ms Access Query Group By employee ID

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have written this query which shows the desired output if I don't use `groupby  [Service Order Labor].EmployeeID` clause

What I am trying to achieve is list out all work order's assigned to employees, so if there are multiple records for one single employee it should be written as a group

```
SELECT [Service Order Labor].WorkorderLaborID, [Service Order Labor].WorkorderID, Customers.ID AS CustomerID, Customers.SiteName AS Customer, [Service Orders].ProblemDescription, Employees.[EmployeeID#] AS EmployeeID, Employees.EmployeeName, [Service Order Labor].SERVICED AS StartDate, [Service Orders].DateFinished AS CompletedDate, [Service Order Labor].DISPATCH, [Service Types].Type, [Service Orders].[PRIORITY#], [Service Orders].COMPLETE, [Service Order Labor].ACTIVE
FROM (((Customers INNER JOIN [Service Orders] ON Customers.ID = [Service Orders].ID) INNER JOIN [Service Order Labor] ON [Service Orders].WorkorderID = [Service Order Labor].WorkorderID) INNER JOIN Employees ON [Service Order Labor].EmployeeID = Employees.[EmployeeID#]) INNER JOIN [Service Types] ON [Service Orders].Type = [Service Types].TypeID
ORDER BY [Service Order Labor].SERVICED, [Service Order Labor].WorkorderID group by  [Service Order Labor].EmployeeID;
```

**The Error is**

[image]

Comment: "groupby" needs a space: "group by"

Comment: You'll also need to use `group by` correctly. Consider using the query designer.

Comment: @JeremyCook I did changed it to group by same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retire some "(" try:

```
 SELECT  [Service ORDER Labor].WorkorderLaborID,
     [Service ORDER Labor].WorkorderID,
     Customers.ID       AS CustomerID,
     Customers.SiteName AS Customer,
     [Service Orders].ProblemDescription,
     Employees.[EmployeeID#] AS EmployeeID,
     Employees.EmployeeName,
     [Service ORDER Labor].SERVICED AS StartDate,
     [Service Orders].DateFinished  AS CompletedDate,
     [Service ORDER Labor].DISPATCH,
     [Service Types].Type,
     [Service Orders].[PRIORITY#],
     [Service Orders].COMPLETE,
     [Service ORDER Labor].ACTIVE
FROM Customers
INNER JOIN [Service Orders]       ON (Customers.ID = [Service Orders].ID)
INNER JOIN [Service ORDER Labor]  ON ([Service Orders].WorkorderID = [Service ORDER Labor].WorkorderID)
INNER JOIN Employees              ON ([Service ORDER Labor].EmployeeID = Employees.[EmployeeID#])
INNER JOIN [Service Types]        ON ([Service Orders].Type = [Service Types].TypeID)
ORDER BY
  [Service ORDER Labor].SERVICED,
  [Service ORDER Labor].WorkorderID 
group by 
  [Service ORDER Labor].EmployeeID;
```

Comment: You should write the error down, instead of posting a link to a picture

Comment: Consider run without 'group by' and check. I think this query dont need GROUP. Consider not use '#' in column name.

Comment: @AndreTurina without group by it works great but shows different records for each employees . so for example for employee id 1000 there are 2 records, the result should should show 1000, WorkorderID1, WorkorderID2

Comment: @AndreTurina distinct of?

Comment: To remove duplicates rows without **GROUP BY** add word **DISTINCT** after **SELECT** and before the rest of code. Like `SELECT DISTINCT name FROM myTable` .